# Return Array from Function lost values

Tags: php, arrays

can't explain the following Problem: i have a php function returning the following array. When i do a Print_r within the function the array echos as follows:

```
Array ( [title] => Even&Odd Shopper Bag Handtasche Damen in Schwarz [brand] => Even&Odd [category] => Shoes [ProductTypeName] => HANDBAG [Department] => Damen [bildpfad] => https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31w5kOgS2BL.jpg [Prices] => Array ( [Var_HighestSalePrice] => [Var_LowestSalePrice] => [Var_HighestPrice] => [Var_LowestPrice] => [Offer_HighestPrice] => [Offer_LowestPrice] => 2495 [uvp] => 2995 ) [Discount] => 17 [available] => in stock [Color] => Schwarz [error] => )
```

if i return the array when calling the function from another php and then print_r the response. there are some values lost. Here the value "color" and "bildpfad" and the array looks as follows:

```
Array ( [title] => Even&Odd Shopper Bag - Handtasche Damen in Schwarz, Rot, Blau o. Cognac-Braun - Tasche aus Kunstleder mit Reißverschluss & Handyfach [brand] => Even&Odd [category] => Shoes [ProductTypeName] => HANDBAG [Department] => Damen [bildpfad] => [Prices] => Array ( [Var_HighestSalePrice] => [Var_LowestSalePrice] => 2495 [Var_HighestPrice] => 2995 [Var_LowestPrice] => 2995 [Offer_HighestPrice] => [Offer_LowestPrice] => [uvp] => ) [Discount] => [available] => in stock [Color] => [error] => )
```

I tried nearly everything with addslashes, trim the fields etc. etc. any ideas what this could be?

UPDATE: The Function

```
function getAmazonData($region, $asin) {
    $xml = aws_signed_request($region, array(
        "Operation" => "ItemLookup",
        "ItemId" => $asin,
        "IncludeReviewsSummary" => False,
        "ResponseGroup" => "Images,ItemAttributes,OfferFull,VariationSummary",
        'MerchantId' => 'All'
    ));
    $error= $xml->Items->Request->Errors;
    $item = $xml->Items->Item;  
    $response = array(
            "title" => htmlentities((string) $item->ItemAttributes->Title),
            "brand" => htmlentities((string) $item->ItemAttributes->Brand),
            "category" => htmlentities((string) $item->ItemAttributes->ProductGroup),
            "ProductTypeName" => htmlentities((string) $item->ItemAttributes->ProductTypeName),
            "Department" => htmlentities((string) $item->ItemAttributes->Department),
            "bildpfad"=> htmlentities((string) $item->LargeImage->URL),
            "Prices" => array(
                "Var_HighestSalePrice" => htmlentities((string) $item->VariationSummary->HighestSalePrice->Amount),
                "Var_LowestSalePrice" => htmlentities((string) $item->VariationSummary->LowestSalePrice->Amount),
                "Var_HighestPrice" => htmlentities((string) $item->VariationSummary->HighestPrice->Amount),
                "Var_LowestPrice" => htmlentities((string) $item->VariationSummary->LowestPrice->Amount),
                "Offer_HighestPrice" => htmlentities((string) $item->OfferSummary->HighestNewPrice->Amount),
                "Offer_LowestPrice" => htmlentities((string) $item->OfferSummary->LowestNewPrice->Amount),
                "uvp" => htmlentities((string) $item->ItemAttributes->ListPrice->Amount)
            ),
            "Discount" => htmlentities((string) $item->Offers->Offer->OfferListing->PercentageSaved),
            "available"=> "in stock",
            "Color" => htmlentities((string) $item->ItemAttributes->Color),
            "error" => htmlentities((string) $error->Error->Code)

            );  


Print_r($response);
return $response;
};
```

call the function and print result:

```
$response = getAmazonData("de", $parent);
Print_r($response);
```

Comment: So you think we can imagine code of your function and fix problem, right?

Comment: @u_mulder: hmm, could be a point. ;-) I'll check if i can update the question.

Comment: @u_mulder: now with function and function call.

Comment: And now what? `print_r()` after function call shows not the same data as `print_r()` inside a function? In your current code it is __impossible__

Comment: @u_mulder: jep that's it. and i dont know why? Within the array after the function call there are missing the values, "color" & "bildpfad"

Comment: Obviously something happens between function call and `print_r`, otherwise it is impossible. But you don't show us __what__ happens

Comment: Just a little number formatting: $price=number_format((float) (max($response['Prices']) / 100), 2, ',', '');
$sale_price=number_format((float) (min(array_diff($response['Prices'], array(0,''))) / 100), 2, ',', '');

Comment: This is a simple sample https://3v4l.org/hNHh5. Works fine, so, there's something you don't show us.

Comment: Let me guess: you tried to simplify the question by putting the array literal inside the function, while in reality you get it via an HTTP request. But that is an essential difference. You cannot get an asynchronously retrieved result in a synchronous way. Use a callback function.

Comment: @trincot: thanks for feedback. no it's not via HTTP Request. The Function is in another php file. The file is include('function.php'); i'm not familiar with callback functions, but had a short look at it and think its not necessary.

Comment: and in 99% the $response is similar, but not in that case shown above.

Comment: If it really is like that for you (I cannot reproduce this), your installation of PHP may be corrupted. But before going that route, I would first reduce the code to the bare minimum to still produce the problem. For instance, can you reproduce this with an array that is much smaller in size, with maybe just 2 key/value pairs? Can you reproduce it by hard-coding the XML instead of calling `aws_signed_request`, ...etc. Can you reproduce it without using XML at all? Eliminate as much as you can.

Comment: @trincot: hmmm...yeah, at the end i have to do that. but i had the hope someone here find the bug :-( thanks a lot.